# Spring mvc resources mapping not working in jboss

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

Static content of my project are working fine on tomcat 7 when I run it on localhost, but when I deploy it in jboss server in openshift cloud, It cannot load the static content like `css` and `javascripts` and says **404 page not found**.

```
href="/css/style.css;jsessionid=VYqVk+kw7xnnnFWOs1XO4t+P.undefined"
```

I see this `undefined` at the end of the jsessionid. what does it mean?

**servlet mapping**

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

**servlet xml**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

resources directory is inside webapp.
I am using eclipse with maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Jboss are you using?

If it is 7.1.1, there is a bug related to the jsessionid with ".undefined" suffix

Loo at https://community.jboss.org/thread/201097 and https://community.jboss.org/thread/201760

Comment: Yes it was 7.something version. Later on I replaced jboss with tomcat. Thanks for your reply.